# Determine whether there exists a contiguous subarray of length > 1 with an integer mean

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an unsorted array of integers.

I'm trying to come up with an efficient solution (better than O(n<sup>2</sup>)) but the best I can come up with is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution:

```
for i from 0 to size of list:
    sum = list[i]

    for j from i + 1 to size of list:
        sum += list[j]

        if sum % (j - i + 1) == 0:
            return true
return false
```

I've read stuff on sliding window technique, but it looks like that would be useful for subarrays of a specific length *k*.

Comment: I assume array is not sorted?

Comment: Yes the array is unsorted.

Comment: Check this out, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476927/longest-contiguous-subarray-with-average-greater-than-or-equal-to-k

Comment: I don't think preprocessing the cumulative sums would help as you would still need to iterate through every start and end index i and j...

Comment: Better than O(n) is out of question, you need to read all elements !

Comment: I'm sorry, better than O(n^2)

Comment: Is it a question from an online judge ? In that case can you provide the link ?

Comment: Agreed with fjardon. Please add the source/inspiration for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a trick question :) Two odd numbers sum to an even number and two even numbers sum to an even number. The only data set that would not include a contiguous subarray of length two that's also divisible by two would have to alternate `[..., odd, even, odd, even, ...]`. But then the data set would need to be even further restricted to prevent a subarray of length 4 to be divisible by four, since every other even number is divisible by four.

The probability of receiving such a list is extremely small and continues to reduce as the list gets larger (what's more, it lends itself to a subset of numerical patterns; could those be of interest?), which means unless someone worked painstakingly to create some, most if not all real-world situations would find a solution with a sliding window of size 4 that also checks for alternating parity.

Comment: It's rarity doesn't mean impossibility. Also this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If you truly claim it is impossible, then sure, it becomes an answer. But you didn't claim that until now (your answer literally only says 'extremely small probability'), and provide no evidence for such claim.

Comment: @orlp an SO answer is not required to be a complete answer. Also, statistically significant information about how algorithms do over many engagements with data, rather than just one, are commonplace (for example when describing behaviour of sorting methods). Being able to make such a claim about this problem is important and useful information.

Comment: And I can prove that for any size list there exists a solution: simply the alternating array of 0s and 1s. No subarray has integer mean because a subarray of length k > 1 always has sum 0 < s < k and thus can't be divisible by k.

Comment: @orlp you've just pointed to a possible solution by detecting such patterns :)

Comment: `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...` `1, 2, 1, 10, 5, 10, 1, 30, 1, 10, ...` `1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 14, 9, 42, ...` There are multiple possibilities at each step; I don't see this being limited to an easily detectable pattern.

Comment: @m69 isn't the pattern of `sums 0 < s < k` detectable in better than O(n^2)?

Comment: That's not the only valid pattern. None of my examples uses it.

Comment: @m69 not sure what you're suggesting... are you providing patterns where the solution is `false`? Is there a method to your construction?

Comment: When I say valid sequences, I mean they can go on with  the result remaining false, but they don't follow the rule that 0 < s < k like 0,1,0,1,0,1... does. To construct them I deviated from 1,2,1,2,1,2... at some point and then took the smallest possible value at each step (without using 0). But at any point you can choose a higher value, so there seems to be no limit to the number of "valid" sequences, nor an easily detectable pattern.

Comment: @m69 how would one automate the creation of N lists of length 1000 with a false result? (lacking the sums 0 < s < k condition)

Comment: Use the lowest option at each point, and then backtrack at each step and use the second-lowest option? That would give you 2^1000 different sequences. And as far as I can tell, the number of options at each step may be unlimited.

Comment: @m69 how do we guarantee we're not creating a window of arbitrary size (like 7 or 41) we haven't checked for? Or is creation O(n^2)?

Comment: @m69 in any case, my point is Math.random isn't going to cut it :)

Comment: Yes, creating such a sequence involves checking every length of subsequence up to that point. And I did that by hand :-)

Comment: The point is that there may be a huge number of (or even infinitely many) sequences that don't have a k-sized subarray with a sum divisible by k, and no easy way to spot a "true" or "false" one. You could take a huge false one and change one value, and you'd still have to do an almost complete check to find the "true" part.

Comment: @m69 sure but the chance of getting one that wasn't carefully man-made is next to none for any significant size list.

Comment: That's true, but if this is from an online judge, they'll have at least one such test to check the worst-case performance of your algorithm.